# Most efficient method of returning coefficients for a fit in Python for use in another languages?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, differential-equations, stan

So, I have the following data I've plotted in Python.
[image: Temperature vs. Day]

The data is input for a forcing term in a system of differential equations I am working with. Thus, I need to fit a continuous function to this data so I will not have to deal with stability issues that could come with discontinuities of a step-wise function. Unfortunately, it's a pretty large data set.

I am trying to end up with a fitted function that is possible and not too tedious to translate into Stan, the language that I am coding the differential equations in, so was preferring something in piece-wise polynomial form with a maximum of just a few pieces that I can manually code.

I started off with `polyfit` from `numpy`, which was not very good. Using `UnivariateSpline` from `scipy` gave me a decent fit, but it did not give me something that looked tractable for translation into Stan. Hence, I was looking for suggestions into other fits I could try that would return functions that are more easily translatable into other languages? Looking at the shape of my data, is there a periodic spline fit that could be useful?

Comment: Would a sinusoidal fit work?

Comment: A purely sinusoidal fit does not.

Comment: Perhaps use the FFT and get rid of the higher frequencies?

Comment: @potpie, Why not? Because it's not portable in the wanted way? Because it's missing features you want to capture?

Comment: @MikeGraham, what particular sinusoidal fit/package do you have in mind? I tried a standard sin/cos function fit with `scipy`'s `leastsq` and it did not work so well, though maybe I did not do a good enough job there. I initially tried fitting to a*(sin(b*x+c) + d.

Comment: @Jaime, what is FFT?

Answer (score 1):

The UnivariateSpline object has get_knots and get_coeffs methods. They give you the knots and coefficients of the fit in the b-spline basis.

An alternative, equivalent, way is to use `splrep` for fitting (and `splev` for evaluations).

To convert to a piecewise polynomial representation, use PPoly.from_spline (check the docs for the latter for the exact format)

If what you want is a Fourier space representation, you can use leastsq or least_squares. It'd be essential to provide sensible starting values for NLSQ fit parameters. At least I'd start from e.g. max-to-max distance estimate for the period and max-to-min estimate for the amplitude.

As always with non-linear fitting, YMMV, however.

Answer (score 0):

From the direction field, it seems that a fit involving the sum of or composition of multiple sinusoidal functions might be it.
Ex: sin(cos(2x)), sin(x)+2cos(x), etc.
I would use Wolfram Alpha, Mathematica, or Matlab to create direction fields.